# Ggplot2 geom_line error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a daaset which consists of data points over a time series for the proportion of people living in urban/rural areas for a number of countries. Sadly, not all countries have data for the same years. I have been trying to produce a simple line plot to show the different proportions of people living in different locations by year, but as each country has a different number of data points I am running into trouble.

I think this is because some of the countries only have data for a single year and using  `geom_line` from `ggplot2` throws the following error:

> geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

I was hoping that there would be some way to override this, or perhaps just plot a single point where a COUNTRY only has data for a single year. Does anyone know if this is possible, or indeed, if this is actually what this error means?!!?

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Here is my data:

```
    structure(list(COUNTRY = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Comoros", 
"Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Namibia", "Rwanda", "South Africa", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe")), Year = structure(c(5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 
16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 
9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 
24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 
8L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 
22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 
21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 
20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 
22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 
13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 
8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 
5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 
6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 
9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 
5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 
7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 
19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 
1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 
4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 
24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 
7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 
24L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 
23L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 
1L, 24L, 21L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 18L, 
10L, 4L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 24L, 17L, 8L, 3L), class = "factor", .Label = c("1992", 
"1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", 
"2000/1", "2001/2", "2002", "2003", "2003/4", "2004", "2005", 
"2005/6", "2006", "2006/7", "2007", "2007/8", "2008/9", "2009", 
"2010", "2011")), location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Urban", 
"Rural", "Total", "Capital.City", "Other.Cities.towns", "Urban.Non.slum", 
"Urban.Slum"), class = "factor"), percent = c(63.0434782608696, 
93.8, 87, 79.5642604795185, 65.4240807416892, 63.0791092522326, 
90.448386469558, 85.9419999774024, 92.7603614781794, 84.0437368780105, 
89.9792286718626, 91.0916571421351, 87.1132950026762, 73.8624315865239, 
60.8311005575454, 66.7, 96, 86.8, 90.6243926153181, 90.6911141749493, 
90.7602286016099, 93.0377175475414, 86.073106379954, 84.253722056373, 
77.8178199148702, 97.3, 91.8332260789258, 89.612164524266, 89.9070989918367, 
94.9, 85.1351949905457, 94.8358752154967, 92.9, 89.656599879838, 
90.2634019334124, 94.4, 91.6241263241579, 76.7337303943862, 68.4233513070184, 
74.15601627144, 88.4802888646634, 85.4643913454376, 89.7457528950664, 
81.3025210084024, 83.0579155525397, 71.5857386620092, 86.2324062094295, 
87.687478493975, 63.5379061371841, 78.5, 40.7, 51.7763728811622, 
32.2441768813334, 22.3138981723172, 83.3699691175754, 69.6742912391579, 
76.0526239692028, 83.7290062290807, 77.4758329101792, 83.8081963934296, 
67.5805226154664, 55.8951299980461, 41.9921451192584, 52.2, 92.5, 
77.6, 82.0322170392223, 85.2850090044269, 70.8031150919282, 47.108593681531, 
82.2215412952297, 78.3643348536815, 74.4253468485616, 94.8, 90.1711142192198, 
85.0338348718722, 86.3134329333052, 90.4, 79.2813256726705, 90.7077549957666, 
82.5, 77.7236217339155, 75.3278238729086, 77.7, 78.4592126267142, 
67.1145693585691, 55.3459024734839, 57.8463881286199, 83.5604620304044, 
83.9259722574938, 84.4589780509803, 73.3992444632325, 77.544833952707, 
63.0503715222555, 75.6808008503601, 85.6943513045284, 63.4, 84.2, 
51, 55.7151220012609, 34.9, 26.6, 85, 72.5, 79.2, 83.8, 80.3, 
84.9, 69.6, 59, 46, 54, 93, 78.7, 83.2, 85.9, 76.7, 57.5, 83.8, 
80.4, 75.6, 95, 90.4, 85.6, 86.9, 90.6, 82.2, 91.5, 84.5, 79.9, 
78.1, 80.9, 81.2, 68.1, 56.8, 59.6, 84.9, 84.4, 86.5, 77, 79.1337842548663, 
65.6, 79.1, 86.3, 68.421052631579, 96.1, 93.3, 93.461209969107, 
82.2712525836501, 88.2708936990495, 87.6298001816506, 87.6386027991385, 
93.1818181818183, 86.6666666666668, 88.1030398041979, 90.4761904761904, 
83.4297434324662, 86.3744073211853, 83.6107223166148, 78.3, NA, 
72.8, 80.952380952381, 87.5, 96.9073193030442, 99.1348508752745, 
85.5297651573129, 86.4793919321843, 79.4520547945208, 98.2, 92.4613307718678, 
85.4590408924955, 83.9378238341966, 92.1, 81.1594202898552, 96.0232554251852, 
NA, 88.0377726639494, 83.690767555447, 93.4, 90.0349966633017, 
71.2508707571865, 72, 79.4082828804656, 91.8032786885246, 84.5238095238095, 
87.8787878787881, 75.6097560975609, 81.0643061692494, 68.4708412135189, 
84.9056603773584, 89.5522388059702, 61.6438356164384, 91.7, 79.5, 
77.0004220956012, 61.061381883032, 58.756042602018, 91.2594694272412, 
85.20149612163, 92.4956062313464, 82.622382662868, 91.4036416540165, 
91.6169313256523, 89.2957214499669, 67.6757501795213, 48.1479760952102, 
NA, NA, 94.2, 94.3553068539161, 91.8799748693178, 89.3739230258784, 
92.1418739343887, 86.4757947454868, 81.0102236379536, 77.0100025126874, 
NA, 91.3720851411616, 92.2, 92.5003150086683, 97.8260869565219, 
87.1461797069698, 93.5168077834096, NA, 90.1780793791367, 92.9758067301415, 
94.9, 91.8829499602467, 81.749280834314, 65.1853441661798, 69.0503609949116, 
87.2562445664681, 85.8298270239758, 90.6673511683335, 83.2861189801694, 
84.9006282245266, 73.65452177457, 87.3075692692965, 85.5310215524833, 
83.3333333333333, NA, NA, 98.5990187756088, 84.4640706359058, 
NA, 93.9158337759274, 91.5744358611439, 100, NA, NA, NA, 88.7824144772468, 
85.1972665683085, 89.54493171236, NA, NA, 89.8, NA, 100, 97.6261376125643, 
96.3196943955923, 92.0952338262334, 87.9266080431752, 80.9429968520701, 
NA, NA, 92.8, 95.2886158200472, 100, 86.4199793410402, NA, NA, 
89.9001648604344, NA, NA, 91.5033109800214, 83.8918470610424, 
73.9339911532972, 88.6921281548131, 94.309068022859, 85.3299585067346, 
93.7362934447331, 86.5384615384618, 83.7424288707868, NA, 86.3836615391687, 
88.1866796344726, 58.1081081081081, NA, NA, 75.7976468146464, 
62.1289432084197, NA, 88.1488735873722, 84.2108238885019, 89.8335978405451, 
NA, NA, NA, 86.9222656846515, 70.3584041024493, 70.9023609260137, 
NA, NA, 85.9, NA, 89.8689917369566, 90.3864925686512, 92.628169473785, 
80.9468895007753, 78.7885741638367, 75.4005791241575, NA, NA, 
88.4, 87.7139456942162, 92.3809523809525, 83.7645232075473, NA, 
NA, 89.567507133125, NA, NA, 91.6433898994358, 73.6225283043976, 
65.9223049858496, 72.3148320483822, 86.2596215693035, 85.6224026570651, 
87.4940330171337, 78.7499999999997, 81.9949404453665, NA, 84.5563115043796, 
87.0190820047277)), .Names = c("COUNTRY", "Year", "location", 
"percent"), row.names = c(NA, -336L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to produce a simple plot with ggplot2 that is facetted by COUNTRY. I can do this fine using `geom_point`:

```
ggplot(meas_melt, aes(Year, percent, colour=location))+ geom_point() + facet_wrap(~COUNTRY)
```

However, if I try and produce a line plot with geom_line (`ggplot(meas_melt, aes(Year, percent, colour=location))+ geom_line() + facet_wrap(~COUNTRY)`)

I get the following error:

> geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

I had thought that this could be because a couple of the countries have only one year's worth of data so I subsetted the date to remove these three countries like so:

```
ggplot(meas_melt, aes(Year, percent, colour=location))+ geom_line(data=meas_melt[!meas_melt$COUNTRY %in% c('Comoros','South Africa','Swaziland'),]) + facet_wrap(~COUNTRY)
```

However, I get the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sven's answer is correct but fixes only part of the problem. Note how there's no plot for Comoros, South Africe, or Swaziland. This is because in your data, sometimes year is, e.g., 2006 or 2007, and sometimes it is "2006/7".

```
data[meas_melt$COUNTRY=="Swaziland",]
      COUNTRY   Year           location  percent
32  Swaziland 2006/7              Urban 94.83588
80  Swaziland 2006/7              Rural 90.70775
128 Swaziland 2006/7              Total 91.50000
176 Swaziland 2006/7       Capital.City 96.02326
224 Swaziland 2006/7 Other.Cities.towns 93.51681
272 Swaziland 2006/7     Urban.Non.slum       NA
320 Swaziland 2006/7         Urban.Slum       NA
```

Those countries really have only one "year" (hence, no line). More importantly, these odd year designations distort your x-axis. You can see that using the `scales="free"` argument to `facet_wrap(...)`:

```
ggplot(meas_melt, aes(x=Year,y=percent, color=location)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=location)) +facet_wrap(~COUNTRY, scales="free") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=8), 
        legend.position="bottom")
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `aes(group = location)` inside `geom_line`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(meas_melt, aes(Year, percent, colour=location)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = location)) + 
  facet_wrap(~COUNTRY)
```

[image]